# FTDI eeprom programming using linux command line

Tags: ftdi

We have a FTDI device, FT2232H and an EEPROM M93C46-WMN6TP. Is there a utility or a way to program the eeprom in Linux using command line? We do not have provision for GUI in Linux or for connecting it to a windows system.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample EEPROM folder provided with the driver package that cab used for programming the EEPROM device (/release/examples/EEPROM/write/ )

Write can be checked used the read program in /release/examples/EEPROM/read/

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely program an EEPROM with a FT232H, but you will have to write your own program.
I am more a Windows person, but the code should similar on Linux.

I just sent a tweet yesterday doing just this with an FT4222 board 
that I will use for my USB device Nusbio v2.
https://twitter.com/MadeInTheUSB/status/808868754146914304

A video experimenting with the FT232H
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i8_EFs_j0I

The EEPROM M93C46-WMN6TP protocol seems to be SPI
see [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/m93c46-w-955034.pdf) page 6

I suppose you may already have an FT232H evaluation board, so once wired on a breadboard to your EEPROM all the 4 SPI wires (CLOCK, MOSI, MISO, CS) you can start talking to the EEPROM.
Unfortunately the source code from one EEPROM to another thing can change.
I know very well the I2C 24LC256 family and the SPI 25AA1024.

Some of my code is available on github, this is for the SPI EEPROM 25AA1024,
that should help

[MadeInTheUSB.Nusbio.SPI.EEPROM_25AA1024](https://github.com/madeintheusb/Nusbio.Samples/tree/master/CS/MadeInTheUSB.Nusbio.SPI.EEPROM_25AA1024)

[MadeInTheUSB.Nusbio.Components/EEPROM](https://github.com/madeintheusb/Nusbio.Samples/tree/master/MadeInTheUSB.Nusbio.Components/EEPROM)

You can find a 100% already made solution hardware and software at

[Nusbio Thumbdrive](https://squareup.com/market/madeintheusb-dot-net/item/nusbio-thumb-drive-kb)

Using the source mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see how this is answering the question, regarding a Linux cli tool to program the ftdi